# what should I do in my app to support sending data between two iphones in wifi?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what should I do in my app to support sending data between two iphones in wifi or bluetooth?
for example I want to send text from one device and receive and open the text in the other device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out what [Bump](http://bu.mp/api) has to offer:

> The Bump API uses the Bump matching
>   technology to identify another mobile
>   phone and then creates a messaging
>   channel between the two handsets. Your
>   users will be able to establish
>   connections, exchange data,
>   authenticate interactions...

**Updated:**
You could also have a look at Apple's [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which offers peer-to-peer connectivity.

Comment: Is there any other free commercial API or any API of apple?  Can 2 iphone devices connect through wifi and transfer data?

Comment: Updatd my answer to include Apple's Gamekit